# How to make MOD_WSGI app to run Python in 32-bit mode?

Tags: python, 32bit-64bit, mod-wsgi, cherrypy

I seemingly tried everything and I failed to achieve to run Python in 32-bit mode.

So here is my situation:

I am running OSX 10.8. I developed CherryPy app that has to connect to Oracle 10g2 database. There is a well-known issue that prevent CX_Oracle to work in 64-bit, thus the requirement to run in 32.

```
<IfModule wsgi_module> 
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/WSGI-Executables">
AllowOverride None
Options None FollowSymLinks
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
SetEnv CONFIG_PATH /Users/bioffe/src/Icap/trunk/cgi-bin
SetEnv ORACLE_HOME /Applications/ORACLE/instantclient_10_2
SetEnv TNS_ADMIN /Applications/ORACLE/instantclient_10_2
SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /Applications/ORACLE/instantclient_10_2
SetEnv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH /Applications/ORACLE/instantclient_10_2
SetEnv VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT yes

</Directory>
WSGIPythonHome  /usr/local/bin/python2.7-32
WSGIPythonPath /Library/WebServer/WSGI-Executables
WSGIScriptAlias /etc  /Library/WebServer/WSGI-Executables/ETCConfWebApp.py
#WSGIDaemonProcess etc_config user=bioffe group=wheel threads=4 python_path=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
ProxyPreserveHost On
SetEnv VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT yes

</IfModule>
```

**App's code**

```
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self):
    result = ''
    for key, value in os.environ.items():
        result += key + '=' + value + '\r\n'

    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type']= 'text/plain'

    result += '*' * 10
    result += '\rCurrent Dir = %s \r' % os.getcwd()
    result += '__file__ = %s \r' % __file__
    result += 'PID=%d \r' %  os.getpid()
    result += 'PPID=%d \r' % os.getppid()
    result += 'UID=%d \r' % os.getuid()
    import threading
    th = threading.current_thread()
    result += "ThreadID=%d name=%s \r" %(th.ident,th.name)
    result += "ThreadPool Size=%d \r" %(cherrypy.server.thread_pool)
    result += "ThreadPool Max Size=%d \r" %(cherrypy.server.thread_pool_max)
    import sys
    result += "%s \r" %(sys.version)
    result += "%d \r" %(sys.maxint)
```

**Output**

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
**********
Current Dir = /Library/WebServer/WSGI-Executables 
__file__ = /Library/WebServer/WSGI-Executables/ETCConfWebApp.py 
PID=16170 
PPID=16167 
UID=70 
ThreadID=140735313402208 name=MainThread 
ThreadPool Size=10 
ThreadPool Max Size=-1 
2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 25 2011, 05:09:01) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] 
9223372036854775807 <- 64 bit, I want to see 32-bit's 2147483647
```

Here is what tried so far:

1. To force Python by setting environment variable

   export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes

   This one is ignored by WSGI_mod. os.environ contains only one *PATH* environment variable
2. To force Python by setting defaults value and make it accessible to _www(70) user.

   defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes
3. To create virtualenv and lipo thin i386 executable out of it

   WSGIPythonHome  /usr/local/bin/python2.7-32
4. To create thin executable into default python environment, didn't work.
5. To compile mod_wsgi link using python2.7-32's headers and *.sos.

Nothing works. I was wondering of someone could shed some light on this issue.

BONUS Q: 
I added

```
WSGIDaemonProcess etc_config user=bioffe group=wheel threads=4 python_path=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

I see extra https process that is run with UID bioffe, however my app still being processed by httpd process with UID _www. How come my request is being processed by different httpd process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnMacOSX#Forcing_32_Bit_Execution

Also be aware SetEnv doesn't set environment variables. For mod_wsgi it sets per request environ variables which are passed in a dictionary to the WSGI application on each request. Thus, you cannot SetEnv to set process environment variables.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#Application_Configuration

As to WSGIDaemonProcess, you likely are missing the required WSGIProcessGroup that needs to go with it.

Please ensure you are reading the mod_wsgi documentation on the official mod_wsgi site as such details are covered there.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#Defining_Process_Groups
- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#Delegation_To_Daemon_Process

You possibly have some other things wrong, but too hard to tell as no detail provided which would help to confirm that.